# Averaging from several rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, ndvi

I need to take an average of several rasters using ArcGIS. Suppose there are 6 rasters and want to have an average of all those 6 rasters. How can I do so?

Comment: Cell statistics tool.

Comment: I am using arcmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FelixIP suggested in the comments, you want to use [Cell Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm). Note that this requires a license for the Spatial Analyst Toolbox.